# iPhone: Quicker UITextView Scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, scroll, uitextview, chat

I have a text view named chat (it s part of a chatroom program). I want to automatically scroll whenever the user enters something to the bottom. So, whenever the user enters something, I called the code below. It works fine, but it is a little slow. I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this that would be almost instantaneous (i.e. the user enters something and then instantly it is scrolled down to what the user last entered). Here is my current code:

```
[chat scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(chat.text.length, 0)];
[chat setScrollEnabled:NO];
[chat setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the end of the text document *instantaneously*, i.e., without animation, you can use the following:

```
[chat scrollRectToVisible:[chat caretRectForPosition:chat.endOfDocument] animated:NO];
```

The issue with `-[scrollRangeToVisible]` is that it effectively uses the private UIScrollViewScrollAnimation class to update the contentOffset property of your UITextView on a timer, thus, the scrolling animation.

You could also use `-[setContentOffset:animated:]`, passing `NO` as the second argument.  This is available via UIScrollView, which is the base class of UITextView.  However, you would have to determine the content offset manually.